# Zune desktop - play count on new machine

Tags: zune, zune-software

I'm at my wits ends with this. What should be something very simple just doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I have moved my music library to my new machine. It is in exactly the same location (same username as well). I copied %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Zune -> The new PC.

Now something absolutely bizarre is happening. It's got some play counts recorded - but they're way off what they should be.

I've looked at Process Explorer and confirmed the databases. I've replaced the database multiple times on the new PC and it still has the wrong counts.

Can anyone fill me in on where the hell I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why not just let it re-index your source?

Comment: Because I want play counts maintained

Comment: @Sam I am using Zune 4.8. Where is any playcount visible?

Comment: Old question but if you go to the Song view, it's there.

Answer (score 0):

when you mention play counts, are you concerned about keeping the ones on the "social" service associated with your account -- or just the ones locally in your collection?

If the former, note they are stored in the service and so you can reset your collection DB, move machines, etc and they won't be lost.